# Trying geolocalizing using geoplugin javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to go to a specific language page using ip from a list of countries.
Is this code correct?

```
if(geoplugin_countryCode() != 'US'){
        if(geoplugin_countryCode() == 'FR'|| =='CH' || =='LU' || =='BE' || =='LI'){
location.href = "indexfr.html";
}else{
location.href = "//index.html";
}
```

Any help welcome
Thanks

This works
Not Run, But this works

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
if(geoplugin_countryCode() != 'US'){        
        if(geoplugin_countryCode() == 'FR'){
location.href = "indexfr.html";
}else{
location.href = "//index.html";
}        
}
</script>
if (Type == 2 && (PageCount == 0 || PageCount == '')) {
```

I just want to add more countryCode

Comment: No, it's not correct. Missing closing bracket. Also `=='CH' || =='LU'` is syntax error, you must compare something with string. E.g.  `code == 'CH' || code == 'LU'`. You don't even try to run this code, right?

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into a [Mixed Content error](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).

If your HTML page is on a `https://` URL, your browser may refuse to include the geoplugin.ne script because its URL starts with `http://`.

To check using Chrome, you can open the Developer Tools console (ctrl+shift+J) and look for this error message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<your domain here>/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```